# Архитектура клиент-серверного приложения SQL + C# WPF

Tags: sql, wpf, entity-framework, архитектура, клиент-сервер

Вопрос по архитектуре клиент-серверного приложения.

Есть база данных SQL Server.
Есть бэк-офис - WPF приложение, которое работает с БД через Entity Framework, через него оператор правит что нужно в БД.
Нужно сделать клиенское приложение, тоже WPF и раздавать заказчикам, они в свою очередь будут работать с той же БД как клиенты. По сути клиент легко сделать урезав некоторые функции уже готового бэк-офиса. Это было бы оптимальным, т.к. трудозатраты будут в разы меньше, чем переделывать.
Но! Бэк-офис же работает с БД напрямую, соответственно я должен каждого заказчика регистрировать как пользователя БД? Тогда, чтобы он не смог сделать что-нибудь плохое с БД, мне нужно закрывать ему права на изменения таблиц и.т.д.? В случае, если сделать так - то клиент получит возможность, как минимум, увидеть структуру БД (открытых для просмотра таблиц) через какой-нибудь клиент SSMS?

Или это делается по-другому и нужно обязательно писать какой-то сервис-прослойку между клиентом и БД?

Comment: Сделай WCF сервис общий для всех и для бэка и для клиента (так они оба будут юзать один код). Клиент просто не будет знать как обратиться к твоим методам предназначенных для бэка. profit

Comment: Можно поподробнее? Т.е. к базе обращается сервис WCF, а приложение будет получать от него уже другие объекты DTO?

Comment: WCF это посредник, в нём у тебя будут все запросы к бд и возвращаться будет в нужном формате на клиенты (на бэк или офис).
Твоё дело будет тупо дёргать методы WCFа, а WCF уже сам всё сделает и отдаст что тебе нужно.

Comment: И сервис WCF работает с каждой клиентской машины через один и тот же БД-аккаут при этом? Если да, то как в нем зашивается логин-пароль от БД?

Comment: WCF обычно работает на одной машине вместе с базой данных (но можно и удаленно сделать) и там же будет храниться инфа о коннекте с бд (если нужно - то можно создать для него отдельного юзера с разграничением прав). А клиентам вообще будет плевать откуда идут данные и как они хранятся, они просто дёргают WCF методы

Comment: Ок, начал понимать. Буду копать в эту сторону, спасибо!

Comment: @Shamil, перенеси в ответ, я приму. Ты мне очень помог.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделай WCF сервис.
Он будет прослойкой между бд и клиентами. Только сервис будет хранить настройку подключения к бд (если нужно - то в бд можно создать для него отдельного юзера с разграничением прав), там же в сервисе ты напишешь все необходимые действия над данными в виде методов, а клиенты будут их вызывать. Таким образом про базу данных будет знать только WCF, а клиенты уже получать готовые данные.